# How can I make a JS function work on a new opened window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension and I can't make call the function to work on the newly opened window.
I cant call `alertit()`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var buttonn = document.getElementById("startt")
  buttonn.addEventListener("click", openerr)
}

function openerr() {
  var newwin = window.open(" https://www.instagram.com/explore/people/?hl=fr");
  alertit();
};

function alertit() {
  alert("wiiii")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Thanks Ivar for editing the question

Your grammar and description is pretty poor, so I'll try and get what you are intending.

So, you are opening a window with your chrome extension, and want to alert on it. This can't be done to my knowledge by calling window.open then directly something else, as they are two seperate things.

To control the new page, I suggest you use a content script: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration

Best of luck

Comment: brother am tring to execute  the alertit function after the finction openerr is done opening the new tab so the alert box appeare in the new tab the the function openerr opened

Comment: @FADIX And I explained there is no easy way to do that.